# Passing value from DropDownList to model's list

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

So I have a drop-down that is created using DropDownListFor, it displays fine but the data is not sent correctly to the controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("sendTestData", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post))
{
    var cnt = 0;
    foreach (string question in ViewBag.Questions)
    {
        <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(x => question)</h3>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.answers[cnt], new SelectList(ViewBag.Answers))
        cnt++;
    }
    <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

The model being used in question has a list named answers, and i'm trying to pass the value of each dropdownlist created into the model's list.
The controller being used has the following function

```
public void sendTestData(Model model)
{
    //business logic
}
```

The model:

```
    public class Model
    {
        public List<string> answers = new List<string>();
    }
```

I check the value of the list: model.answers and it's merely an empty list, no data is being put in it.

Answer (score 0):

What I can see is your model properties don't initialize properly.

If you write the model properties like that, answers will work like variable because they just initialize the data (list string), not receiving the data from your view.

You can write the model properties like this

```
public class Model
{
    public List<string> answers { get; set; }

    public Model(){
        answers = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** -- Some suggestion

I don't know why you pass the question on ViewBag instead of model. Maybe you have some reason. But if me, I will create code like this

Model class:

```
public class Question
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public List<string> AnswerList { get; set; }
    public string AnswerSelected { get; set; }
}

public class MainModel
{
    public List<Question> QuestionList
}
```

View:

```
@model ...MainModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("sendTestData", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post))
{
    var cnt = 0;
    foreach (string question in Model.QuestionList)
    {
        <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.QuestionList.Question)</h3>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.QuestionList.AnswerSelected , new SelectList(Model.AnswerList))
        cnt++;
    }
    <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Controller:

```
public void sendTestData(MainModel model)
{
    //business logic
    //Loop through QuestionList
}
```

Because one of my reason use MVC is strongly type model binding. So I will use model in form processing instead ViewBag.